# Why the gridview layout breaks in IE7?

Tags: css, gridview, internet-explorer-7

http://210.22.155.222/group/3431/explore-learncentral

You  can see it by simply clicking the **Members** tab.

It's fine in Firefox and IE8, each `<tr>` contains 4 items,

but in IE7, the layout is broken,each `<tr>` with only 2 items.

What's wrong in IE7?

Comment: Your site is very slow. How about posting some HTML instead?

Comment: @Michael Todd ,the HTML is too much, would you see it on site?

Comment: try tidying up your html, its filled with invalid html. I snipped your ajax response, cleaned up errors, loaded it both on IE7 and FF and its worked fine. http://pastebin.com/znhhr3yp

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to your page, see what happens when you turn compatability view on/off?